# UWP application in Assigned Access mode loses focus after CTRL+ALT+DEL

Tags: windows, uwp, uwp-xaml, kiosk-mode

I have an UWP application that runs in Assigned Access (Kiosk mode). When the PC boots up and the user logs in, the application starts in assigned access and the user can use the TAB button to navigate within the app.

However, after locking the PC (CTRL+ALT+DEL) and logging in again, the focus is lost. You have to use the mouse and click somewhere on the application to bring the focus back.

I was able to identify that after locking the PC with CTRL+ALT+DEL and logging back in, the application that has the focus is the "Assigned Access Lock app".

I have tried some workarounds to set the focus back using SetForegroundWindow from user32.dll, but no luck.

Does anyone know what is going on here? Is this a bug or expected behavior?

PC setup:

Windows 10 Enterprise 22H2

OS build: 19045.2728

It doesn't seem to be related to application, because I have tried to with simple UWP app. Here is the MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page x:Class="TestUwp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestUwp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="419,385,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="115" Width="385"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="419,568,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="120" Width="294"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I have tried below, but the result is the same:

- different UWP apps
- set the focus back using SetForegroundWindow from user32.dll

Comment: I too have this issue, did you ever find a solution? I've added a timer to focus a control on the view every n seconds as a workaround.